# How to get the product of two field into another field in each button click

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have 3 textboxes.product of two  textboxes are get into another textbox automatically.the fields are quantity and per/unit.then these two is multiplied into the field amount in each click.But the problm is i got the product in first click only..

**js**

```
                var new_string='<div class="form-group" id="exp_'+unqid+'">'
                +'<label for="exampleInputPassword1">'+name+'</label> </br>'
                 +'<input name="quantity_'+unqid+'" type="text" id="quantity" style="margin-right:20px;"  class="form-con"  placeholder="Quantity" required>' 
                +'<input name="perunit_'+unqid+'" type="text" id="perunit" style="margin-right:20px;" onchange="getTotalAmount('+unqid+')" class="form-con"  placeholder="Per/unit" required>' 
                +'<input name="amount_'+unqid+'" type="text" id="amount"   class="form-con" placeholder="Amount" required></div>';
                 $("#create").append(new_string);
```

**called function**

```
     function getTotalAmount(unqid)
        {
           alert(unqid);

            var q = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            //alert(q);
            var p = document.getElementById("perunit").value;
           // alert(p);
            if(q!='' && p!='')
                {
                var total = p * q;
                // alert(total);
                document.getElementById("amount").value = total; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I got the uniqid in each button click..but the product display only once

Comment: where is your JS add more function or code ?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: what you mean by fiddle?

Comment: @Arthi: JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) is an online tool where you can create frontend code and share with others. Just go through the link mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :
html code

```
Value 1<input type="text" id="t1"><br/>
Value 2<input type="text" id="t2"><br/>
Result<input type="text" id="t3">
```

js:

```
$('#t2').blur(function(){
var a = $('#t1').val();
var b = $('#t2').val();
var c = a*b;
$('#t3').val(c) 
});
```

and check at https://jsfiddle.net/ejzn66n5/